# How to link a local repo to a remote in Github

Tags: git, github

As the title, I want to link local repo to remote.

***Description*:**

- I have a repo and remote are linked (as normal).
- I delete the git folder at local repo (I lost local repo).
- I try to reconnect them by using "git init" and "git remote add origin [https://github.com/myrepo.git"](https://github.com/myrepo.git%22).
- The new local is looked like a new empty repo, every subdir or branches on my old repo now untracked (Figure 1).

**Figure 1:**

[image]

***Question:***
What is the git command help me to make the new repo is 100% same the old in the description step 3.

Thank!

Comment: clone remote repo locally

Answer (score 0):

You have simply to clone it by `git clone https://github.com/myrepo.git`.